# Magento 2 + Varnish + Nginx + SSL get real IP

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish, ssl

I'm having a setup for Magento 2 with Nginx + Varnish + SSL in ubuntu server 18.04. Now with my setup, I only get all logs in Nginx and inside Magento admin coming from same localhost IP which Varnish listens.

I want to change that.

What the best way to do it?
Using Nginx and

> ngx_http_realip_module

Or reconfigure Varnish with a GeoIP module I found here:
[Varnish GeoIP](https://belvg.com/blog/geoip-redirect-and-varnish-in-magento-2-part-1.html)

For option one will this add in my Nginx conf file work?

```
server {
    listen 8082;
    set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
    <Other Server Options>
}
```

Do I need to change something in Magento

> Nginx.conf

file?

Comment: how is your request going? because `nginx` on port `:80` hardly the right place.

Comment: @MagenX sorry for this. I corrected in my question the conf file. Request goes to varnish first as my setup is configured with nginx as proxy pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to help you debug this, you can add this php file for example, `headers.php`:

```
<?php
foreach($_SERVER as $key_name => $key_value) {
print $key_name . "  =  <font style='color: rgb(0,0,255);'>" . $key_value . "</font><br/>";
}
?>
```

where you can see all the headers.

make sure you proxy pass correct header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

add remote IP variations and check headers with file above.

Comment: Although this was not the solution for my problem it helped me to solve it

Comment: impossible to write something specific, we dont see your configuration

Comment: you are absolutely right. Question wasn't for getting the configuration. Question was if it is better to use `ngx_http_realip_module` or `Varnish geoip`

Comment: great it actually working :)